# Can I attach Haddock comments to declarations in a `[d|…|]` declaration quote?

Tags: haskell, ghc, template-haskell, haddock

If I have a declaration quote passed to a Template Haskell function, something like

```hs
someTHFunction
  [d|
    -- | Some documentation
    data SomeType = SomeConstructor | SomeOtherConstructor
    |]
```

is there a way to access the Haddock comment `Some documentation` inside `someTHFunction :: DecsQ -> DecsQ`?  I tried using `getDoc` with the `SomeType` name from inside the `DataD`, but that fails with

```
Example.hs:(7,1)-(11,6): error: [GHC-24922] …
    ‘SomeType_0’ is not in scope at a reify
```

---

Concretely, suppose `someTHFunction` is a simple Template Haskell identity function that also calls `getDoc`:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module SomeTHModule where

import Language.Haskell.TH

someTHFunction :: DecsQ -> DecsQ
someTHFunction decsq = do
  decs <- decsq
  let names = [name | DataD _ name _ _ _ _ <- decs]
  _ <- traverse (getDoc . DeclDoc) names
  pure decs
```

If I try to use that in another file, I get the above error:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Example where

import SomeTHModule

someTHFunction
  [d|
    -- | Some documentation
    data SomeType = SomeConstructor | SomeOtherConstructor
    |]

{-
Example.hs:(7,1)-(11,6): error: [GHC-24922] …
    ‘SomeType_0’ is not in scope at a reify
-}
```